# Can a person who was declared Undesirable in South Africa Transit through South Africa going to another country?

Tags: transit, overstaying, south-africa

I was declared Undesirable in South Africa in 2018 because i overstayed, I want to travel to Malawi but the flights are connecting in South Africa, will they allow me to transit through South Africa to Malawi?